# Use more than one before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter, rubycas

I want to use two filters in application_controller so, if the first filter fail:

```
before_filter CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter
```

try it with the second:

```
before_filter :hmac_filter
```

The idea is when someone tries to enter to the REST service through a web client, 
the petition must be filtered with the rubycas client filter and if someone tries to enter with, for example, a client that use CURL, with the first filter should fail, but the second must be applied given the adequate parameters.
I could use a sequence of curl petitions with the first filter activated for authenticate and gain a session cookie, but is not the idea, I must to use hmac_filter. Neither I can modify hmac_filter.

Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT**

Maybe it wasn't the best solution, but at last this was my implementation:

```
before_filter :choose_auth

def choose_auth
  params[:hmac_auth] ? hmac_filter : CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter.filter self
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before filters run before processing any web requests at all, so I don't think that this is going to help your situation.  You need to handle this type of thing at the action level.